# Single quatation mark in column name

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to execute the following:

```
UPDATE door_instances SET pt_id = '9906662', 0221RUMSNUMMER = 'C0962', 0311HNGNINGHV = 'V', 0312Angreppssida = 'Gångjärnssida', 083FUNKTIONSKRAVLJUDISOLERINGKlassR\'wdB = '30', 131KARMVGGTJOCKLEK = '145', ingrejirapport = 'Nej', isFinished = 'Nej', isNew = 'Nej', 211FRKLARINGAROCHFRESKRIFTER = '', 212GRNSDRAGNING = '', 213KANALISATIONDRRMILJ = '', 215RITNINGAR = '', 216DETALJER = '', 214BESKRIVNINGAR = '' WHERE id IN (105239)
```

But because one of columns have quotation mark in name (  083FUNKTIONSKRAVLJUDISOLERINGKlassR\'wdB ) I'm getting this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'wdB = '30', 131KARMVGGTJOCKLEK = '145', ingrejirapport = 'Nej', isFinished = '' at line 1
```

Any idea or suggestions will be appreciated.

Common MySQL guru's.

Comment: You will need to enclose the column name in backticks as `\`083FUNKTIONSKRAVLJUDISOLERINGKlassR'wdB\``

Comment: If you are in any position to change the column name so it _doesn't_ include a single quote, I would recommend doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short: don't do this.

Longer: you can use the backtick ` to quote column names:

```
...da', `083FUNKTIONSKRAVLJUDISOLERINGKlassR'wdB` = '30', 131KARMVG...
```

to use them in PHP, put that in between single or double quotes:

```
$key = '`'.$key.'`'
```

or

```
$key = "`$key`"
```

Comment: Yes, I know how that is working but I don't know how to add backticks in PHP to variable. They somehow disappear when I try something like this $key = ` . $key . `;

Comment: @PottaG just put them inside the string. In PHP the backtick has no special meaning. See my updated answer.